# Css Bootstrap affix menu is not showing auto scrollbar on my MacBook Pro

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, affix

I have a website where I am using an [css bootstrap affix menu](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix).

Due to the length of my menu, I need to add an automatic vertical scrollbar when the screen is not long enough.

I added the a class named `scrollspy-y-fix` on both container `ul` element and also to the container `<nav class="col-sm-3">` to force a scrollbar to show up when the screen is smaller than the menu.

.scrollspy-y-fix {
    height: 100vh !important; 
    overflow-y: auto !important;
}

It seems to be working great in all browsers, except for when I use my MacBook Pro. On my MacBook using Safari or Google Chrome, I don't get a scroll bar. The menu is half way visible and I can't scroll down to see the item at the bottom of the menu.

Here is the site for evaluation https://crestapps.com/laravel-code-generator/docs/1.0

How can I fix this issue?

Here is a screenshot from my MacBook Pro. As you can see there is no scrollbar.

Additionally, on a regular screen PC, the selected item on the menu does not change as I am scrolling down the page. Any idea why?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding "overflow: scroll;" to the css.